# sqlalchemy + pymysql + gevent

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, gevent, pymysql

I'm new to python but it seems like an interesting language, so I'd like to go on learning about it.

I've been searching for information on this subject but I can't seem to find anny decent sources.
I've installed Python3.3, Pymysql, SQLAlchemy, (Pyramid) and MySQL.

Connecting to the database with pymysql works fine using this connection string. I use pymysql because I want to make asynchronous calls to the database (gevent) and I need SQLAlchemy so I can do object mapping.

I'm currently working in the pythonWin screen to test if we can connect to our database.

```
import pymysql    
con = pymysql.connect(db='dbeerste', user='admin', passwd='admin', host='localhost', port=3306)    
cur = con.cursor(); 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dbeerste.tabel1;")
```

Combining these 2 doesn't seem to work for me.

```
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://admin:admin@127.0.0.1/dbeerste")
engine.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1651, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.__connection = connection or engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1709, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.unique_connection()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 220, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 425, in __init__
    rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 777, in _do_get
    con = self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 225, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 322, in __init__
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\event.py", line 381, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\event.py", line 398, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 168, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py", line 2052, in initialize
    default.DefaultDialect.initialize(self, connection)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 172, in initialize
    self._get_default_schema_name(connection)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py", line 2019, in _get_default_schema_name
    return connection.execute('SELECT DATABASE()').scalar()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 664, in execute
    params)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 808, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 871, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.3.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 322, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql3-0.4-py3.3.egg\pymysql\cursors.py", line 96, in execute
    #query = query % conn.escape(args)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'
```

Can anyone help me on this plaese, I'd be greatful for any response

ps: As I'm new to the language I'd love to hear any response, also if anyone has any suggestions to do this another way, please type your opinion.
I'm not bound to a lot of things, only Python3.3, asynchronous calls and using MVC.

Comment: the pymysql dialect probably hasn't been tested yet on python 3 and needs a few tweaks.    Feel free to post a ticket following the instructions here: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/participate.html#bugs  thanks !

Comment: I found the solution to this but I can't answer my own question :p
In the C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql3-0.4-py3.3.egg\pymysql\cursors.py file. 
change this rule (commented below) in the rule right under it. restart pythonwin and it works fine.

`if args is not None:
     #query = query % conn.escape(args)

     query = query.decode(charset) % conn.escape(args)`

Comment: the code you need to change is on line 96 like displayed in the error message

Comment: probably not, assuming pymysql runs on Python 3 we'd need to not be sending it "bytes" in the first place, is the issue.   we're probably doing an "encode" where we shouldn't be.

Comment: fixed to problem for me though ...